# Find count of unique column elements after using groupby with pandas

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, count

I have a data set that is setup like the following:

```
rows = [
    ('us', 0, 'ca', None, 94107, -100),
    ('ca', 1, None, 'bc', 94107, -100),
    ('us', 0, 'ca', None, 94106, 0),
    ('us', 0, 'ca', None, 94107, 0),
    ('ca', 1, None, 'bc', 94107, 0),
    ('ca', 1, None, 'bc', 94107, 0),
    ('us', 0, 'ca', None, 94107, 100),
    ('us', 0, 'ca', None, 94107, 100)
]
```

I want to group by: `(country, state/provence, zip)` and then find the counts of the `Option` column AFTER the grouping is completed, and then finally convert to a dict.

Ideally I would like the dict to be formatted as such:

```
{
    ('us', 'ca', 94107): {100: 2, -100: 1, 0: 1}, 
    ('us', 'ca', 94106): {0: 1},  
    ('ca', 'bc', 94107): {-100: 1, 0: 2}
}
```

I have the following code so far:

```
# build the data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Country', 'LocFilter', 'State', 'Provence', 'Zip', 'Option'])

# consolidate "State" and "Provence" into "MainProvence" based on "LocFilter"
df['MainProvence'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['Provence'] if row['LocFilter'] == 1 else row['State']), axis=1)

# group by and find distribution
distribution = df.groupby(by=['Country', 'MainProvence','Zip', 'Option'])['Option'].count()
# print the result
print distribution
```

This gives me the following - which looks good:

```
Country  MainProvence  Zip    Option
ca       bc            94107  -100      1
                               0        2
us       ca            94106   0        1
                       94107  -100      1
                               0        1
                               100      2
Name: Option, dtype: int64
```

However, when I convert this to a dict:

```
print distribution.to_dict()
```

I get this:

```
{
    ('us', 'ca', 94107, 100): 2, 
    ('us', 'ca', 94106, 0): 1, 
    ('us', 'ca', 94107, -100): 1, 
    ('ca', 'bc', 94107, 0): 2, 
    ('ca', 'bc', 94107, -100): 1, 
    ('us', 'ca', 94107, 0): 1
}
```

Which is understandable based on how I formed the groupby. I could obviously manipulate the returned dict in python to get the format that I want - but is there any way to get this format using pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is super easy. Try:

```
distribution.unstack(level=['Option']).to_dict(orient='index')
```

To get

```
{('ca', 'bc', 94107): {-100: 1.0, 0: 2.0, 100: nan},
 ('us', 'ca', 94106): {-100: nan, 0: 1.0, 100: nan},
 ('us', 'ca', 94107): {-100: 1.0, 0: 1.0, 100: 2.0}}
```

I think dropping the `nan`s shouldn't be too much of an inconvenience at this point.

---

PS. Consider using:

```
df['MainProvence'] = df['State'].fillna(df['Provence'])
```

in place of

```
df['MainProvence'] = df.apply(lambda row: (row['Provence'] if row['LocFilter'] == 1 else row['State']), axis=1)
```

---

PPS. You will need Pandas 0.17 for the `orient` kwarg to work inside `to_dict()`.

Comment: Worked great! I'm still learning pandas and must have missed the stack/unstack. Also great tip about fillna. And thanks for including the version note, I had to bump my pandas version and then it worked great.

Comment: Glad to help you! Even I missed quite a bit of features in my early days. I'd recommend reading through the documentation of Pandas. It can get boring, so pace it out.